# UICollectionView datasource method not called after reload data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to fetch data from website and add to my collectionview, but the problem when I called [self.collectionView reloadData], it's not working.

So my code is as following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [PYBSkuApi getSKUList:1 andHotId:@"17" success:^(NSArray *skuList) {
        self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:skuList];
        [self.skuCollectionView reloadData];
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
}


// Data source 

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return [self.dataSource count];
}

- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
....
}
```

The problem is when I reload the collection view, after the self.dataSource is updated, it goes into

```
 - (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
```

But never goes into

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I don't know why.

Comment: What does `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` return? Is `numberOfItemsInSection` called?

Comment: Is it returning the count?

Comment: To be sure that you have connect "Delegate" and "Datasource" for collection view.

Comment: Yes, it returns 8, and I added delegate and datasource for itself

Comment: Did u give Cell identifiers name  correctly in storyboard?

Comment: Did you also check the outlet is connected and not nil?

Comment: why do you return 1 in numberOfItemsInSection and not 
return [self.dataSource[section] count]; ?

Comment: @jithin Yes, I checked they are the same and I am not using storyboard, but register the cell as class, the name is the same. Also I set the outlet correct, I think

Comment: Can you try to call '[self.skuCollectionView reloadData];' outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with same problem (sometimes an `UICollectionView` does not call `dataSource`'s methods after `reloadData`).
An UICollectionView rebuilds list in `layoutSubview` method, you can know it if you have set breakpoint in some `dataSource`'s method. To force an `UICollectionView` reload list, you should invalidate the layout of that collection view:

```
<...>
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionView setNeedsLayout];
[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
<...>
```

Comment: Holy smokes this helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever called setCollectionViewLayout or initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

or

```
_collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```